# How to compare two lists of objects?

Tags: c#

I have a simple class in C#:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
}
```

The Customers are stored in a List CustomersA and additionally i have a second with List CustomersB. CustomersB is the "Truth".

I need to find out

- customers in CustomersB but not in CustomersA (by CustomerID)
- customers in CustomersA but not in CustomersB (by CustomerID) (the same as above)
- customers in CustomersB also with the same CustomerID in CustomerA but different CustomerName

How could i achieve this with C#?

Comment: I suggest you read up on LINQ - it makes everything like that pretty simple. Then you can try it for yourself, and ask a more specific question including what you've tried and the problems you've run into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397897.aspx) for set operations on data:

•customers in CustomersB but not in CustomersA (by CustomerID)

```
var query = customersB.Where(cB => !customersA.Any(cA => cA.Id == cB.Id)).ToList();
```

•customers in CustomersA but not in CustomersB (by CustomerID)

```
var query = customersA.Where(cA => !customersB.Any(cB => cB.Id == cA.Id)).ToList();
```

•customers in CustomersB also with the same CustomerID in CustomerA but different CustomerName

```
var query = customersB.Where(cB => customersA.Any(cA => cA.Id == cB.Id 
                                                  && cA.CustomerName != cB.CustomerName))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: I marked up but i think technically the **Question owner** should change the **question title**....this isn't really **comparing objects** its more querying objects for **filtering**.

Comment: @Seabizkit It's comparing two sets in order to filter them. Nothing wrong with the question title.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning on doing these comparisons in multiple places, you could also create a custom [`EqualityComparer<Customer>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123(v=vs.110).aspx) and re-use them wherever needed.

This is an example of two comparers, one based on Id and another based on Id and Name. I'm going to assume a customer id is unique in this example:

```
public sealed class CustomerByIdEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Customer>
{
    public bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return x.CustomerId == y.CustomerId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Customer obj)
    {
        return obj.CustomerId;
    }
}

public sealed class CustomerByIdAndNameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Customer>
{
    public bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return !string.Equals(x.CustomerName, y.CustomerName) &&
                x.CustomerId == y.CustomerId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Customer obj)
    {
        return obj.CustomerId;
    }
}
```

And you consume them using `Enumerable.Except`:

```
var comparerById = new CustomerByIdEqualityComparer();
var comparerByIdAndName = new CustomerByIdAndNameEqualityComparer();

var customerARelativeComplement = customersA.Except(customersB, comparerById);
var customerBRelativeComplement = customersB.Except(customersA, comparerById);
var customersBRelativeComplementByName = customersB
                                         .Except(customersA, comparerByIdAndName);
```

If you're working with large sets, consider using [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the filtering. Only problem with it is that you can only pass a single `EqualityComparer<T>` to it and you'll be bound to it.

Comment: Shit, I was finishing my answer with basically the same text ;P

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer LOL, sorry: X

Comment: NooooooOOOOOOooooooOOo!! You've stolen my points!! Nah, it's a joke :D